# 'Observable<any>'. Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'NativeFs'

Tags: typescript

vscode hover 'exists' can show the error:

```
[ts]
Argument of type 'NativeFs' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<any>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'NativeFs'.
```

this is the source code:

```
interface NativeFs {
  <T>(...args: any[]): Rx.Observable<T>;
}

let readFile: NativeFs = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(fs.readFile);
let exists: NativeFs = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(fs.exists);

hierarchyPath$
  .takeUntil(exists) // <- "exists" error
```

I've got in the console:

```
src/entity/index.ts(27,14): error TS2345: Argument of type 'NativeFs' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<any>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'NativeFs'.
```

tsc version info:

```
tsc -v
Version 2.5.3
```